# iCal event repeat set to M,W,F - showing up as S,T,R!

Tags: drupal, date, icalendar, rrule

I have an iCal event specified in UTC with repeats. Everything appears to be output properly, yet iCal clients are flailing: the repeat pattern is M,W,F but the start date (translated to UTC) is a Tuesday.

The repeat pattern being incorrectly calculated is S,T,R.

This is the ical output that is not working properly:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME: Room ICCS008
PRODID:-//Drupal iCal API//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:calendar.18861.field_date.0.8
SUMMARY:CPSC 210 L2C
DTSTAMP:20110518T123628Z
DTSTART:20110621T010000Z
DTEND:20110621T033000Z
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR;UNTIL=20110730T033000Z
URL;VALUE=URI:https://localhost/event/2011/06/cpsc-210-l2c
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The event is supposed to start June 20th at 6:00pm PST. The calendar rightly translates this to June 21st at 1:00am for UTC. It repeats M,W,F for a month. However it seems to be totally throwing off both Google Calendar and Apple iCal's calculation of the repeat events.

The first event is showing up on Monday, but the second is on Tuesday, the third Thursday, and from then on it's S,T,R for the repeating pattern until the end.

Is this an iCal bug? Is this something that is being output wrong by my iCal creator (Drupal's Views iCal)?

**UPDATE:** Ok, lots of people have imported this and it works in all cases except on Apple iCal and Thunderbird Lightning.

This is because on import clients are (I believe) globally-scoping the timezone and shifting everything in one go, correctly.

However if you *subscribe* to it with GCal, it individually-scopes each of the events' times and goes kerplewey, showing the behaviour I described above.

**UPDAT-IER**

The iCal file itself is wrong - for some reason certain clients can handle the wrongness and others can't, but the event as specified in UTC is actually repeating every T,R,S at 1:00am, and the "good" clients shift this back based on the local TZ. The iCal creation-process calculated the repeat days based on the local timezone rather than the converted-to-UTC-one. This is a bug in the Drupal iCal implementation.

Comment: I've tested your exact example in my own iCalendar engine, in Outlook 2003, and in Google Calendar.  I am not able to replicate your problem; in all cases, it appears to repeat Monday, Wednesday, and Friday. My psychic powers suggest that you double-check which timezone your current computer is set to (I'm in EST if it helps). Otherwise, good luck!

Comment: Haha, ok, thanks Chris, good to have it verified that it's me who's crazy and not everybody else =) I'm in PST and I had a user report it, AND I can replicate it in both my Google Calendar and my local iCal client. So hmm... I'll play around with specifying TZs and see if I can shed more light. Thanks!

Comment: A friend confirmed that this worked for them in GCals but NOT in Apple's iCal. Weirder and weirder!

Comment: Import works - subscriptions don't. And it's client-dependent!

Comment: Confirmed: when I import into Google Calendar, I see no errors.  When I subscribe with Google Calendar, I see the errors you describe.

Comment: Thanks for that, Chris. I think the client implementations are spotty, but that the output is also wrong. I suspect it figures the event is actually in the +0 timezone, meaning the recurrence is really specifying MWF in +0, not MWF in -8 or whatever - so it moves it back a day to compensate. In this case the event is really happening every T,R,S at 1:00am GMT (if during the meeting we were rude enough to call somebody in England, we'd wake them up early on Tuesday, Thursday and Saturday morning), and the repeat should likely reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iCal file above is wrong.

For some reason certain clients can handle the wrongness and others can't, but the event as specified in UTC is should actually specify a repeating period of every T,R,S (at 1:00am UTC), and the "good" clients shift this back based on the local TZ to be M,W,F.

The output is calculating the repeat days based on the local timezone where the repeat is input (M,W,F) rather than the converted-to-UTC-one.

So... over to drupal.stackexchange.com =)

Answer (score 1):

Check your CCK date field. Is it set to UTC, Site Time Zone or User time zone?

Make sure it's set to whatever time zone you're using to input dates.

Comment: All other repeating events show up fine, and it's not a TZ problem - I want them in UTC and the times are correct. It's only ones whose start date pushes them over onto another day in UTC.It looks like the calendaring applications are "adjusting" for the UTC when putting events in their own TZ by calculating the repeating date d-1 (so instead of M,W,F it's S,T,R).

What I need to know is if Drupal is putting out the repeat incorrectly, format-wise (looks OK when I look at the iCal spec) and if so, how should it be output? If you import the above into your iCal client you'll see what I mean.